# WooCommerce: Move the "remove product" link in cart under the quantity selector without touching the template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Is it possible to move the "remove product" link from the first `<td>` in the cart under the quantity selector? And delete the first `<td>` with it?

I found the funvtion in the template `cart/cart.php`.
Unfortunately I couldn't find any hooks to change the position or delete the `<td>`.

Is there really no way to change that without touching/copy the template file?

This ist the `<td>` with the quantity field:

```
<td class="product-name" data-title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Product', 'woocommerce' ); ?>">
<?php
if ( ! $product_permalink ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', $_product->get_name(), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) . '&nbsp;' );
} else {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key ) );
}

do_action( 'woocommerce_after_cart_item_name', $cart_item, $cart_item_key );

// Meta data.
echo wc_get_formatted_cart_item_data( $cart_item ); // PHPCS: XSS ok.

// Backorder notification.
if ( $_product->backorders_require_notification() && $_product->is_on_backorder( $cart_item['quantity'] ) ) {
    echo wp_kses_post( apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_backorder_notification', '<p class="backorder_notification">' . esc_html__( 'Available on backorder', 'woocommerce' ) . '</p>', $product_id ) );
}
?>
</td>
```

I don't want to touch the template because it's the only detail that I want to change and couldn't do at the moment. And for that "little" detail I don't want to chage such a big and crucial template file. I don't have to worry about future updates an newer versions of the file.

Comment: why you don't want to "touch the template" ? edit your question to add details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please paste the below code in your current theme **functions.php** file.

```
add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_remove_link','remove_cart_icon',10,2);
    function remove_cart_icon($plink,$link){
        return '';
    }

add_filter('woocommerce_cart_item_quantity','change_cart_remove_link',10,3);
function change_cart_remove_link($product_quantity, $cart_item_key, $cart_item){

    //create new product object
    $_product = new WC_Product($cart_item['product_id']);//product_id

    $cart_remove_link = sprintf(
                                    '<a href="%s" class="remove button button_js" aria-label="%s" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s"><span class="button_icon">&times;</span></a>',
                                    esc_url( wc_get_cart_remove_url( $cart_item_key ) ),
                                    __( 'Remove this item', 'woocommerce' ),
                                    esc_attr( $_product->get_id() ),
                                    esc_attr( $_product->get_sku() )
                                );

    $product_quantity .= $cart_remove_link; 
    return $product_quantity;
}
```

I hope it will help you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use jquery to do that

here it is

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
   jQuery(".remove").appendTo(".quantity");
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that would be a possibility if there is no hook